# Pass specific value to sub-report from main report

Tags: crystal-reports

I need some help with a report I have in Crystal Reports. I have a subreport that runs in the details section of my main report. My main report is structured/grouped like this:

MainPartNumber

ChildPartNumber

Sequence

My subreport is relative to a specific ChildPartNumber & Sequence (these parameters & arguments are passed to the subreport). Users are requesting that the subreport appear in the header of my main report. Is this possible?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your question

Comment: which header? group or page or report

Comment: The subreport is in my page header.